# Vaadin 7 - Set and get attributes into VaadinSession

Tags: authentication, attributes, vaadin

I'm currently using Vaadin 7 for creating a RIA and I'm designing the Login functionality.

The application design is simple:

A **UI class** performs navigation beetwen different **View classes**. In particular, the first displayed View is a LoginView class and after a user has been authenticated the UI class redirects the user towards a MainView.

After authentication I'd like to set User data (eg name and surname) into the session and display it always (no matter what specific view) on the top right corner of the Web Application.

As a begginner I read the Vaadin Book and I firstly used the scheme illustrated in chapter 11th https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.global.html, but it doesn't seem to work as expected, probably because I'm using View navigation scheme.

So I use the following approach:

Once authentication is correctly completed LoginView tries to store user data as a VaadinSession attribute with the following code:

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute("name", name);
```

then UI navigates to MainView and tries to get the name of the user with:

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("name");
```

**but it gets a null value.**

Does anyone know why? I appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using  UI.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute("name", name)

Comment: I've done the same thing and it works. Are you checking if you are putting null values?

Comment: Need more example to help, try posting re-creatable standalone application.

Comment: This works for me, too. I think something is wrong with your name-variable.

Comment: Similar: [*Where to store `UI`-object scoped state in a Vaadin 14 app?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57564699/642706)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest storing the values on the HTTP session instead.

```
VaadinServletService.getCurrentServletRequest().getSession().setAttribute("name", name);
```

and

```
VaadinServletService.getCurrentServletRequest().getSession().getAttribute("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the @PreserveOnRefresh annotation on main class which is extends the UI.
Then you can store variables data in the main class.
You can give it from anywhere (in any View) with ((MyUIClass)UI.getCurrent()).getSomeVariable method expression.

Comment: Not really a correct answer. In Vaadin 7, a user can open multiple web browser windows/tabs, each of them showing their own instance of the same UI class (or even other UI classes). All those windows/tabs belong to the same session. In other words, Vaadin 7 has two levels of scope now: A VaadinSession object has one or more UI objects. See [this article](https://blog.oio.de/2013/02/22/vaadins-variable-scopes-vaadinsession-and-ui/) about these two scopes. For user authentication, you want the higher level scope, the VaadinSession rather than the UI. P.S. See that article about thread-safety!!

Answer (score 0):

I have a guess as to why you get your null value. In most tutorials of modern Vaadin, the navigation pages are created first-thing in the UI as objects. If one of these views instantiated in this process is the MainView. If the label displaying the name sets the String in the constructor of the class, the line:

`label.setValue(VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute("name", name));` will be null is the attribute has not been set by the login function yet.

You need to either update the label showing the user string in the @override `enter()` function, or handle it otherwise.