# Where to store `UI`-object scoped state in a Vaadin 14 app?

Tags: servlets, scope, vaadin, vaadin-flow

## Context (web app)

To store state available to our entire Vaadin app, we can get and set "Attribute" on the [`VaadinContext`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinContext.html) object that represents our entire Vaadin-based web app at runtime. These attributes act as a key-value collection, where the key is of type `String` and the value is of type `Object`.

We access the context by calling `UI.getCurrent().getSession().getService().getContext()`.

## Session (per user)

To store state available to any one user’s session, we can similarly get and set "attributes" on the [`VaadinSession`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinSession.html) object.

We access the session by calling `UI.getCurrent().getSession()`.

## `UI` (web browser window/tab)

These two levels of scope, context & session, are wrappers around their equivalents defined in the [Java Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) specification. But Vaadin effectively has a third, finer level of scope. Vaadin supports multi-window apps, where each web browser window (or tab) has its own content handled by a [`UI`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/UI.html) object. If a user has three windows open within our Vaadin app, that user has three `UI` object instances on the server housed within a single `VaadinSession` object.

So it seems like a common need would be storing state per `UI` (web browser window/tab). So I would expect to see the same kind of `getAttribute` & `setAttribute` methods on `UI` as seen on `VaadinSession` & `VaadinContext`. But, no, I do not see such methods on `UI`.

➥ Is there an appropriate place to store state per `UI` object?

In the olden days, in previous generations of Vaadin, we always wrote our own subclass of UI. So we could always store state by defining member variables on our own `UI`-subclass.  Now, in the days of Vaadin Flow (v10+, currently 14), we are discouraged (forbidden?) from writing a subclass of `UI`.

Before filing a feature-request for such attributes, I want to ask if I missed out on a usual place where folks store their per-`UI` state in current Vaadin-based apps.

Comment: Related: [*Get current VaadinContext and current VaadinSession (both places to store state as “attribute” key-value pairs) in Vaadin Flow*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58036705/642706)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vaadin Flow there is [`ComponentUtil`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/ComponentUtil.html) helper class which has methods to store data with components and UI.

See the pair of `ComponentUtil.setData` methods, one [taking a `Class`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/ComponentUtil.html#setData-com.vaadin.flow.component.Component-java.lang.Class-T-) as key, the other [taking a `String`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/ComponentUtil.html#setData-com.vaadin.flow.component.Component-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) as key, just like the `getAttribute`/`setAttribute` methods found on `VaadinContext` & `VaadinSession`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your solution. I did go ahead and open feature-request [ticket # 6287](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/6287).

Comment: Bug? Your approach fails because the `UI` object is being rapidly and inexplicably re-instantiated over and over again. Create a new Vaadin 14 app, in the "Plain Java Servlet" flavor. Attach an implementation of `VaadinServiceInitListener`, and then add a listener for `UIInitEvent` as shown in the manual. Put a `System.out.println` call in that listener. You will see new UI instances being generated even as you click the "Click Me" button of the default app. Shouldn't the `UI` object be stable for the entire time that browser window/tab is open?

Comment: I posted an example app showing this seemingly crazy `UI` class behavior on the Vaadin Forums: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17810577

Comment: Yes, it is not supposed to be like that and it is causing some headaches, see https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues/473