# Get current VaadinContext and current VaadinSession (both places to store state as "attribute" key-value pairs) in Vaadin Flow

Tags: session, vaadin, instance, key-value, vaadin-flow

In using Vaadin Flow, version 14, I know we can store state as key-value pairs kept as "attributes" via `getAttribute`/`setAttribute`/`removeAttribute` methods found on:

- [`VaadinSession`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.0.alpha2/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinSession.html#VaadinSession-com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService-) (per-user scope)
- [`VaadinContext`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.0.alpha2/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinContext.html) (web-app scope)

How does one access the current object for those classes?

Comment: Related: [*Where to store `UI`-object scoped state in a Vaadin 14 app?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57564699/642706)

Answer (score 3):

## `VaadinSession.getCurrent()` ➙ `VaadinSession`

For that **per-user scope**, the [`VaadinSesion`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinSession.html) class provides a static class method [`getCurrent`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinSession.html#getCurrent--) to access the current instance.

```
VaadinSession session = VaadinSession.getCurrent() ;   // Fetch current instance of `VaadinSession` to use its key-value collection of attributes.
session.setAttribute( User.class , user ) ;            // Register user's successful authentication.
```

## `VaadinService.getCurrent().getContext()` ➙ `VaadinContext`

For that **web-app-wide scope**, you must jump through one extra hoop. The [`VaadinService`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinService.html) class actually represents the web app as a whole. But it delegates the *attributes* feature to the [`VaadinContext`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinContext.html) class, an instance of which is tracked by the current service instance. So [get the service](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinService.html#getCurrent--), and use that to [get the context](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinService.html#getContext--).

```
VaadinContext context = VaadinService.getCurrent().getContext() ;  // Get the current `VaadinService` object, and ask it for the current `VaadinSession` object.
context.setAttribute( ServiceLocator.class , new ServiceLocatorForTesting() ) ;
```

## `VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletContext()` ➙ `ServletContext`

The `VaadinContext` object discussed above does provide web-app-wide scope for saving objects as "attributes" in a key-value mapping. However, notice that the key to must be a `Class`. Sometimes a `String` key might work better.

If you want a String-based key-value mapping across your web app, use the standard [`ServletContext`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). This interface is defined in the [Jakarta Servlet](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/) standard. The [`setAttribute`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-), [`getAttribute`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-), [`removeAttribute`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#removeAttribute-java.lang.String-), and [`getAttributeNames()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getAttributeNames--) methods all use `String` as the key, and `Object` as the value.

```
ServletContext servletContext = VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletContext() ;
```

Store your object as an attribute.

```
servletContext.setAttribute( "map_of_department_to_manager" , map ) ;
```

Since the value does not use [Java Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), we must cast when accessing a stored value.

```
Map< Department , Manager > map = 
    ( Map< Department , Manager > )  // Casting from `Object`. 
    servletContext.getAttribute( "map_of_department_to_manager" )
;
```

If you do have only a single object of a particular class to store, you can use the class name as the string-based key.

```
servletContext.setAttribute( 
    ServiceLocator.class.getCanonicalName() , 
    new ServiceLocatorForTesting() 
) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
ServiceLocator serviceLocator = 
    ( ServiceLocator )                           // Must cast the retrieved object. 
    servletContext.getAttribute( 
        ServiceLocator.class.getCanonicalName()  // Using name of class as our `String` key.
    ) 
;
```